# Problems in the final result (Python)

Tags: python, function, class, calculator

I'm a beginner in python and I'm developing a calculator, creating a class and within it there are 4 functions, being the 4 operations. And in the main only the basic entry. My goal in this program is to use the minimum amount of 'if'.
Is there a way to do this or not?
But, this is giving me an error that I can't imagine how it is happening, it may be in the face but I came here to ask you for help

```
main.py
from calc import *
numero1 = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
sinal = input('Digite a operação: ')
numero2 = int(input('Digite outro numero: '))
retornaValor = 0
retornaValor = Calculadora
print(retornaValor)




calc.py
class Calculadora:

def __init__(self,numero1,numero2):
    self.a = numero1
    self.b = numero2

def soma(self,numero1,numero2):
    soma = self.a + self.b
    print('Resultado: ',soma)

def subtrai(self,numero1,numero2):
    subtrai = self.a - self.b
    print('Resultado: ',subtrai)

def divisao(self,numero1,numero2):
    divisao = self.a / self.b
    print('Resultado: ',divisao)
    
def multiplica(self,numero1,numero2):
    multiplica = self.a * self.b
    print('Resultado: ',multiplica)

Console: 

Digite um numero: 100
Digite a operação: +
Digite outro numero: 30
''<class 'calc.Calculadora'>'' (????)
```

It doesn't bring the result ...

Comment: We can't imagine it either.  Can you paste the whole error into your question?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I'll fix it, because I wrote the code in pt-br. But right after I saw the stackoverflow in portuguese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you're looking for here but you have a few issues to address. I might be missing something but you need to instantiate your class for anything to happen and when doing that you need to supply arguments to your **init** function. I would also suggest that you incorporate some if/else or try/except statements to catch a case where the user gives input that cannot be cast to int(). With that in mind, here is a very simple working example:

```
#get user input (plug for if/else)
numero1 = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
sinal = input('Digite a operação: ')
numero2 = int(input('Digite outro numero: '))


class Calculadora(): #class needs to be defined with ()

    def __init__(self,numero1,numero2): #make sure to supply args here with self 
        self.numero1 = numero1
        self.numero2 = numero2

    def soma(self): #you don't need to supply the input args again if you've already declared above
        soma = self.numero1 + self.numero2
        print('Resultado: ',soma)

    def subtrai(self):
        subtrai = self.numero1 - self.numero2
        print('Resultado: ',subtrai)

    def divisao(self):
        divisao = self.numero1 / self.numero2
        print('Resultado: ',divisao)
        
    def multiplica(self):
        multiplica = self.numero1 * self.numero2
        print('Resultado: ',multiplica)


example = Calculadora(numero1,numero2) #instantiate the class with supplied args
print(example.subtrai()) #call the function you want from inside the class
```

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but it can be easily tweaked to a different format or run slightly differently if you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in the main file

- you have to create an object with the parametre number 1 and number 2 like this :  `my_object_cal = Calculadora(number1,number2)`
- then, you call the right function based on the sign (*+-/) using  `if/elif/else` like this :

```
    if  sign =="+" :
        my_object_cal.soma(number1, number2)
    elif sign == "-" :
        my_object_cal.subtrai(number1, number2)
    elif ...
    else ...
```

you can refer to [this tutorial on if,elif,else](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

you have to learn also [how to create and instantiate object in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)

after that you can advance in [using static methods](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/)

Good Luck.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks for the help, i will study more about...

Comment: @Luiz15K Good luck ;)